# Azure Service Fabric Cluster end point is not accessible

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have created a Service Fabric cluster in Azure portal by following below url.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal

After creating the Service fabric cluster I am not able to browse the "Client connection endpoint" or "Service Fabric Explorer". I am getting Access denioed - HTTP ERROR 403.

I also installed the default certificate on my machine which is creating at the time of Service fabric cluster creation.

When I tried to publish from visual studio I got below errors

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : Cannot bind parameter 'StoreLocation'. Cannot convert value "" to type 
"System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation". Error: "The identifier name  cannot be processed 
because it is either too similar or identical to the following enumerator names: CurrentUser, LocalMachine. Use a more 
specific identifier name."
At C:\CODE\DotNetCode\SFSample\SFSample\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1:185 char:45
 ...     [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ClusterConnectionParameters)
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

WARNING: Unable to verify connection to Service Fabric cluster.
Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection : Cluster connection instance is null

Comment: Can you share the settings you are using to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On you SF project, you have a Publish profile called `Cloud.xml`

You should set the configuration of your cluster in there to tell the thumbprint of the certificate and where you stored it.

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/05/fabrictools">
  <ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="mycluster.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000"
                                    X509Credential="true"
                                    ServerCertThumbprint="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
                                    FindType="FindByThumbprint"
                                    FindValue="9876543210987654321098765432109876543210"
                                    StoreLocation="CurrentUser"
                                    StoreName="My" />

  <ApplicationParameterFile Path="..\ApplicationParameters\Cloud.xml" />
  <CopyPackageParameters CompressPackage="true" />
</PublishProfile>
```

You probably didn't configure it or did in incorrect.